# Closed-form solution vs Python's scikit learn implementation of Linear Regression

Tags: regression, python

I am currently solving a linear regression problem in Python, and tried implementing two methods.

Firstly, I wrote the code from scratch using matrix multiplication and obtaining the theta vector. Used this to make predictions on the data set and computed the MSE.

Secondly, I used sklearn's linear regression implementation and computed the MSE again.

The two values are the same, which I believe is expected, however I wanted to make sure. I looked on the documentation, and sklearn's LR uses the Ordinary Least Squares method, which is a closed-form solution.

However I am a bit unsure if this is the exact same as the general closed-form solution using the normal equation for linear regression or if there should be any difference in the two MSE values computed?

Comment: The Ordinary Least Squares estimator is the same as the estimator obtained from Normal Equations( Maximum Likelihood Estimator assuming Normal uncorrelated errors). Therefore, the MSE from approaches is the same.

Comment: If your design matrix has a large condition number, then accumulated numerical error in $\hat{\beta}=(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top y$ can cause loss of precision, i.e. the resulting $\hat{\beta}$ will be very far from the actual value. In `sklearn`, a more numerically stable approach is used (`scipy.linalg.lstsq`, which in turn uses LAPACK routines).